# Will sqlite database with user infomations gets deleted or reset after new update of app

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I have a question related to **database**, i know this is not a right platform related to question but i know here i can find great developer.

**My query is**,

"I am going to develop an app which deal with `SQLite` 
    Database and a lots of data into the App and user saves a lot data.

so, what if i release new update to play store and user update the app;

*will the user get all the data from the `SQLite` they saved in the previous version of app 'or' the user have to save info again into the database?*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, it won't get deleted.**

> Database will get deleted if it meets following scenarios :
>
> 1. If developer **programmatically** tries to **clean data** of the app / User clears data of the app from **App info page**.
> 2. if Developer upgrades **Database version** after update *(It'll call `onUpgrade()` method in [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) & developer has cleared all
>      table content there)*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you are using the database, but in general what you are searching for is "database migration". You can define how the database should behave on an update (database version increased). If you did not modify your database schema, then it will stay the same as before updating the app.

In case you use room: [Migrating Room databases](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions)

In case you use SQLiteOpenHelper: [onUpgrade](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int))